# two-key alternative to ctrl+shift+c

Tags: linux, keyboard, terminal, keyboard-layout

One of the biggest annoyances when working in a Linux terminal is that copy/paste shortcuts consist of 3 keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>

Especially in laptop keyboards with the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key on the lower left corner, this shortcut is especially challenging to press.

Is there any way to remap it to a 2-key shortcut? E.g. <kbd>Win/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>?

Can this be done on desktop-environment level so that all applications will be able to use the same shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, these shortcuts are specific to your terminal emulator and can be changed in your terminal's settings.

- Using `terminator`.  Right click => Preferences => Keybindings:

  [image]
- Using `gnome-terminal`. Edit => Preferences => Shortcuts:

  [image]

  All non-terminal applications should already be using the 2-key shortcuts.

---

Personally, I never use these shortcuts. One of my favorite features of X is that selecting text anywhere using the mouse copies that text to X's clipboard. Once there, you can middle click anywhere (including a terminal) to paste the copied text. I find this simpler than selecting, copying and pasting using the keyboard since it can be done without moving mu hand from the mouse.